# How to get underlying MessageReceiver reference behind an Azure Service Bus triggered Azure Function V3

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have configured my Azure Function not to 'autoComplete' messages when the Azure Function is triggered. My issue is I need to mark the message complete myself and do so in the context of a transaction (below). This transaction using the 'via' route works in a console app but fails in Azure due to a lack of reference to the original receiver which dequeued the message.

**How to get the underlying receiver reference so I can complete and send atomically?** There appears no way to do this in Azure Functions.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
      try
      {
         await receiver.CompleteAsync(completeMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken);

         for (var i = 0; i <= sendMessages.Length - 1; i++)
            await sender.SendAsync(sendMessages[i]);

         ts.Complete();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         // This rolls back send and complete in case an exception happens
      }
}
```

Without the original receiver reference (and your own newly created reference) you get the following Exception:

```
ERROR: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance.
```

Comment: I can confirm Sean Feldman's answer works as-is perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the message receiver used by the Function to receive the incoming message. Injection is done via function parameters. [This post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/transactional-messaging-with-azure-functions-and-service-bus) goes into details.

Comment: This was a very helpful post. It has gotten me farther, I'm now getting ERROR: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: Transaction hasn't been declared yet, or has already been discharged. So I'm line by line debugging.

Comment: This was the answer to your exact question  The exception is likely due to the code you have in place or the configuration of the Function.

Comment: I also confirmed that my secondary issue was due to the fact that I was creating a new connection object from config instead of reusing the connection passed to the Function's Run() method.

Comment: That'd do it. You don't need to establish a new connection since message receiver will give you own.